# Integer to Vigesimal String

Tags: c

I am trying to convert int to vigesimal base which is 20. The vigesimal number system is base 20. The digits are ’0’, . . ., ’9’, ’A’, . . ., ’J’. I have written code in C language to perform conversion from Int to vigesimal base. But i am not getting the right output. Below is my code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

  int main()
 {
printf("Hello world!\n");
itov('hey',30);
return 0;
}

  void itov(char vigesimalStr [],int n)
{
char base_digits[21] =
     {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G','H','I','J'};

 int  index=0;
 int base=20;

 while (n != 0)
 {
       vigesimalStr[index]= n % base;
       n = n / base;
       ++index;
 }

 /* now print the result in reverse order */
 --index;  /* back up to last entry in the array */
 printf("\n\nConverted Number = ");
for(  ; index>=0; index--) /* go backward through array */
{
      printf("%c", base_digits[vigesimalStr[index]]);
}
printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Simple solution to this problem: 1. Turn on warnings for your compiler (`-Wall -Wextra` options for *gcc* and *clang*). 2. Fix the warnings. 3. If you can't fix the warnings or don't understand them, and there isn't a question about that warning at SO yet, ask what it means and how to fix it.

Comment: Note that you will run into problems converting `0` to a string.  This is one of the places where a `do { … } while (…);` loop is useful.

Comment: Also note that a general purpose `itov()` function will not print the result but make sure that the string is null terminated and in the correct order.

Comment: You should indent your code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is first mistake: (There may be more)

```
itov('hey',30);
/*   ^   ^     */
```

First of all single quotes are used for character literals which are `int` type. You should use double quotes for string literal which is compatible to `char []` (actually depletes to `char *`). Type of such string literal is `const char [SIZE]`.

Secondly because type of literals is `const`, you need to pass a mutable `char` array.

For ex:

```
char converted[20] = {0};
itov(converted,30);
```

--

You should declare the type of `itov` before first usage to be sane and avoid some nasty surprises.

Comment: done with your suggestion but it gives no warning or output when i run it.

Answer (score 2):

This code works with positive numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void itov(char vigesimalStr[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    int tests[] = { 30, 0, 1, 19, 20, 21, 399, 400, 401, 379341, };
    enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };

    printf("Hello world!\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)
    {
        char result[32];
        itov(result, tests[i]);
        printf("%6d = %5s base 20\n", tests[i], result);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void itov(char vigesimalStr[], int n)
{
    char base_digits[20] =
    {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    };

    int index = 0;
    int base = 20;

    do
    {
        vigesimalStr[index++] = base_digits[n % base];
        n = n / base;
    } while (n != 0);

    vigesimalStr[index--] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++, index--)
    {
        char t = vigesimalStr[i];
        vigesimalStr[i] = vigesimalStr[index];
        vigesimalStr[index] = t;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello world!
    30 =    1A base 20
     0 =     0 base 20
     1 =     1 base 20
    19 =     J base 20
    20 =    10 base 20
    21 =    11 base 20
   399 =    JJ base 20
   400 =   100 base 20
   401 =   101 base 20
379341 = 27871 base 20
```

Note that the conversion function does not do any printing — that makes it more nearly generally usable.  The function interface doesn't provide a mechanism to ensure no overflow of the target string; the onus is on the user to provide a big enough string to hold the result.

Handling negative numbers is trickier — perfectly doable, but trickier because on the normal two's-complement systems, you can't negate `INT_MIN` and get a positive value.  You can negate any positive value, though, and then process that.